# Interactive editor for git on windows

Tags: git, github-for-windows

I am using GitHub for windows (http://windows.github.com/). Unfortunately things that require interactive editor (for example - git rebase -i ) are failing in following way.

- open shell provided by GitHub for windows
- use interactive command (git rebase -i or something else)
- Notepad++ opens file produced by git
- I edit, save and close this file
- At this point git should do something based on my edit, unfortunately nothing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close Notepad++ as well.

Solution from http://www.reddit.com/r/git/comments/186uo6/problem_with_interactive_editor_for_git_on_windows/c8c7pi6?context=3

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the full path to your executable set for core.editor in your git config?  if not something like: git config --global "/path/to/editor/" will set it.